# On the Chern connection

Tags: differential-geometry, complex-geometry, vector-bundles, holomorphic-bundles

It is well kown that

> If $\,\bar\partial_E$ defines a holomorphic structure on the complex vector bundle $E \to X$ and $K$ is a hermitian metric on (the fibres of) $E$, there is a unique connection $D$ on $E$ (the *Chern connection*) such that
>
> 1. $D$ is metric, i.e. $K$ is parallel with respect to $D$
> 2. $D^{0,1} = \bar\partial_E$

A Dolbeault-type operator (i.e. Leibniz' rule holds with respect to $\bar\partial$)
$$
\bar\partial_E \colon A^0_X(E) \to A^{0,1}_X(E)
$$
defines a holomorphic structure on $E$ if and only if satisfies the integrability condition $\,\bar\partial_E^2 = 0$. It seems to me that conditions 1. and 2. make perfectly sense  even if the operator $\,\bar\partial_E$ is not integrable, so I conjectured that the statement above holds true in this more general setting.

I thought "maybe the proof itself does not make any use of the integrability of $\,\bar\partial$". But every proof I found begins: "Consider a holomorphic frame..." and this assumption can be made only if $\,\bar\partial$ actually defines a holomorphic structure, i.e. is integrable.

I thus slightly modified the proof in the following way. Does it work?

Conjecture:

> If $\,\bar\partial_E$ is a Dolbeault-type operator on the complex vector bundle $E \to X$ and $K$ is a hermitian metric on (the fibres of) $E$, there is a unique connection $D$ on $E$ such that
>
> 1. $D$ is metric, i.e. $K$ is parallel wth respect to $D$
> 2. $D^{0,1} = \bar\partial_E$

Proof:

The hermitian metric $K$ allows us to reduce the structure group of the bundle to $U(r)$, i.e. we just consider unitary frames.

Suppose that such a connection $D$ exists. From the condition 1. we deduce that in any unitary frame we locally have

$$
D = \mathrm{d} + A
$$

where $A$ is an antihermitian matrix of $1$-forms, i.e. $A + A^\dagger = 0$. Moreover, condition 2. says that $A^{0,1} = C$ where $C$ is the connection matrix of $\,\bar\partial_E$. These two conditions give the equation

$$
A = C - C^\dagger
$$

So $D$ is uniquely determined by $K$ and $\,\bar\partial_E$. To show that $A = C - C^\dagger$ actually defines a connection on $E$ we must check how $A$ changes under gauge transformations $g$. But we know that

- $C \leadsto gCg^{-1} - \bar\partial g \, g^{-1}$
- we can take unitary gauge transformations, i.e. such that $g^{-1} = g^\dagger$

Under such $g$'s we easily see that

$$
A = C - C^\dagger \leadsto g A g^{-1} - \mathrm{d}g\,g^{-1}
$$

as it should be.

Comment: Just a quick comment. One of the reasons this connection is so important is that when you have a holomorphic vector bundle, its curvature will be a $(1,1)$-form. For that you absolutely need integrability.

Comment: This argument looks correct, and can be found in J.P. Demailly's book "Complex analytic and differential geometry" in section V.10.

Comment: What does it mean for $K$ to be parallel to $D$?